# How to make floating action button transform into full screen form

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

In my application I have a FAB and I want to use it to create custom events. The animation I want to achieve is the one labelled under "Full Screen" in the material designs guidelines
https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-transitions

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a 'CircularReveal' animation.  You can use built-in one such as [ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal()](https://github.com/android/animation-samples/tree/master/RevealEffectBasic) but this will require a min-SDK of 21.  If you need the animation on older versions of Android, [there are several libraries](https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal) that are easy to use that achieve this.

As far as using the CircularReveal, just follow the documentation or find a tutorial online.  Typically, you will set an initial circle (size and coordinates) and an end circle (size and coordinates) and when the animation is triggered it will animate the little circle into the big circle.

Comment: Would it then be a case of using an intent/fragment transaction to trigger after the animation has taken place to create the effect from the material designs?

Comment: @smithcommajohn how did you achieve this? Did you ever receive an answer?